# How to construct a trange and use it later?

Tags: python, tqdm

I want to construct `trange` but to use it later. For example:

```
from tqdm import trange

if progress:
    r = trange(10)
else:
    r = range(10)

for _ in r:
    # do something
```

However, at the construction time, `trange` will print an empty progress line (with 0%), and later it will print a new one (as expected).

How to avoid this?

---

Obviously, there are tricks to work around this, for example:

```
for _ in trange(10) if progress else range(10):
    # do something
```

or what @BatWannaBe suggests below.

However, I would prefer something cleaner. Why does `trange` print anything at construction time, in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the progress bar shows up whenever a `tqdm.tqdm` instance is constructed, which `trange` does: `trange(n)` is shorthand for `tqdm.tqdm(range(n))`. I'm not sure if there's any way around that.
However, you can delay the construction by keeping a temporary `range(n)` object.

```
from tqdm import tqdm

r = range(10)

if progress:
    for _ in tqdm(r):
        # do something
else:
    for _ in r:
        # do something
```

If `progress` is `True`/`False`, you could reduce the duplicated code with this trick treating `False` as 0 and `True` as 1:

```
maybetqdm = [lambda x:x, tqdm] # lambda x:x is function that does nothing

for _ in maybetqdm[progress](r):
    # do something
```

Comment: Good idea @BatWannaBe, however, I'm looking for something clearer (see my edit).

Answer (score 0):

Is this cleaner?

```py
from tqdm import trange

progress = False  # We should see no tqdm now

if progress:
    r = lambda n: trange(n)
else:
    r = lambda n: range(n)

for _ in r(10):
    # do something
    ...
```